# select tag in javascript pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

```
var firstpopup = "<input type='image' name='buttonCancel' onclick='hidepopup() ' id='Close' src='../../css/images/closelabel.png' style='text-align:right; vertical-align:bottom;'/><div id='popup'><div class='selected'>You Selected:</div><div id='popupstring' class='sname'> 'Main Kya Karoon Barfi'</div><div class='enter' style='width:414px;height:37px; text-align:left;'><div style='width:150px;float:left;line-height:37px;'>Select Operator</div><div class='operator'><select name='phoneop' id='phoneop'><option>Reliance</option><option>Airtel</option><option>Vodafone</option><option>Tata GSM</option><option>BSNL NORTH</option><option>BSNL EAST</option><option>Idea</option></select></div></div><div class='enter'>Enter your mobile number to <br> set this song as your Caller Tune</div><div id='validationArea' class='validatearea'>&nbsp;</div><div class='mobileno'><div><div class='spann'>+91</div><input name='phonetext' id='phonetext' type='text' class='mobileinput' /></div></div><div class='confirm'><input name='Confirmb' id='Confirmb' type='image' src='../../css/images/confirm.png' class='confirmb' onclick='numberconfirm()' /></div><div class='applicablee'>* charges applicable as per your mobile operators</div></div>";

var secondpopup = "<input type='image' onclick='hidepopup() ' name='buttonCancel' id='Close' src='../../css/images/closelabel.png' style='text-align:right; vertical-align:bottom;'><div id='popup'><div class='selected'>You Selected:</div><div id='popupstring' class='sname'> 'Main Kya Karoon Barfi' </div><div class='enterred' id='confermationvalidation'>Please enter 4 digit code sent on your mobile</div><div class='mobileno'><input name='codetext' id='codetext' placeholder='Enter Code Here' type='text' class='mobileinput'/></div><div class='confirm'><input type='image' name='csubmit' onclick='codeconfirmation()' id='csubmit' src='../../css/images/submit.png'/></div><div class='applicablee'>* charges applicable as per your mobile operators</div></div>";
```

Hi all... I want to skip 'secondpopup' when user selects Reliance or Vodafone from `select` tag. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: what do you mean by skip the second popup?

Comment: I want call another link on the behalf of this link in case of Reliance & vodafone